# what is the best way to handle a 403 status code while web scraping indeed.nl in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape indeed.nl but I'm stuck in one place I can't bypass 403 status code.

I tried passing a cookie to a variable like this;

```py
import requests
url = "https://nl.indeed.com/jobs?q=python+developer&l=Amsterdam&from=searchOnHP&vjk=3a20800b974d57be"
response = requests.get(url)
cookie = response.cookies

re = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)
print(re.status_code)
```

but still, it shows the same message
403 (forbidden)